# Java date checking help Then convert to VB.NET 2010

Tags: java, vb.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010, datetime

I have the following Java code that i am trying to dissect to better understand what all it is doing:

```
try {
     String userName = System.getenv("USERNAME");
     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss");
     OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
     ds.setDriverType("thin");
     ds.setServerName("xxxxxxx");
     ds.setPortNumber(151);
     ds.setDatabaseName("uServer");
     ds.setUser("userhere");
     ds.setPassword("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
     ResultSet rset = null;
     Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(rset.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, rset.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
     rset = stmt.executeQuery("select status, due_date, subject, message, begin_date "
            + "from notifications "
            + "where status = 'OPEN' and recipient_role <> 'SYSADMIN' " + "and recipient_role = 'userhere' "
            + "order by due_date");

     while (rset.next()) {
          try {
               String tempString = rset.getString("begin_date");
               String message = rset.getString("message").replace("\r", "");
               message = message.replace("\n", "");
               String dateString = rset.getString("begin_date");
               int len = dateString.length();
               dateString = dateString.substring(0, len - 2);
               java.util.Date tempDate = new java.util.Date();

               if (dateFormat.parse(dateString).after(tempDate)) {
                   trayIcon.displayMessage(rset.getString("subject"), message, TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
               }

               Thread.sleep(1750);
          } catch (Exception pe) {
               pe.printStackTrace();
          }
     }

     //Fill the table on the Form
     JTable tbl = OracleWorkflowNotifierView.jTable;
     rset.beforeFirst();
     int rsetCount = 0;

     while (rset.next()) {
          rsetCount++;
     }

     if (rsetCount == 0) {
          ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url_green));
          trayIcon.setImage(image.getImage());
     } else {
          ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url_yellow));
          trayIcon.setImage(image.getImage());
     }

     rset.beforeFirst();

     while (rset.next()) {
          java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
          String endDate = rset.getString("due_date");
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
          cal.setTime(today);
          cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -3);

          if (dateFormat.parse(endDate).after(cal.getTime())) {
              ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url_red));
              trayIcon.setImage(image.getImage());
          }
     }
```

I'm not sure what its compairing here?

```
 if (dateFormat.parse(dateString).after(tempDate)) {
     trayIcon.displayMessage(rset.getString("subject"), message, TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
 }
```

Is it looking at the begin date minus the current date?

And then this one:

```
 java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
 String endDate = rset.getString("due_date");
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(today);
 cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -3);

 if (dateFormat.parse(endDate).after(cal.getTime())) {
     ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url_red));
     trayIcon.setImage(image.getImage());
 }
```

Is it looking at duedate minus 3 days from today?

Any help would be great! Thanks :o)

David

**VB.NET CODE**

So, taking the feedback below, would this be a suitable substitution for it in VB.net (the second part of my question)?

```
If Format(dr(1), "MM/dd/yyyy") >= DateAdd("d", 3, Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")) Then
```

And would the first part of my question be:

```
If Format(dr(1), "MM/dd/yyyy") >= DateAdd("d", 1, Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")) Then
```

Where dr(1) = dueDate in both cases above.

Comment: Looks like the logic is pretty much equivalent to the second comparison. But is Format(...) creating a String from a DateTime object? If so, doesn't DateAdd require a DateTime input?

Comment: DateAdd does have a DateTime input, its Now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dateFormat.parse` takes a string and creates a Date object from it (if it is in the given format).

`tempDate` is a Date object that is set to the current date and time.  So

```
dateFormat.parse(dateString).after(tempDate)
```

is checking if the date that is returned from the database (begin_date) is after the current time.

In the second instance `cal` is an instance of Calendar that was set to the current time, then set back by 3 days.  So it is comparing the `due_date` from the database with the current time 3 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
(dateFormat.parse(dateString).after(tempDate))
```

evaluates to true if the date described by `dateString` is after `tempDate`.

```
dateFormat.parse(endDate).after(cal.getTime())
```

evaluates to true if the date described by `endDate` is after today minus 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is checking whether the begin_date (ignoring the last 2 characters, which I'm assuming are seconds) is in the future.

The second example is checking whether the due date is more than three days in the future ((due date - 3 days) is after now).

Comment: My guess is that the last 2 characters are milliseconds, since the DateFormat is expecting seconds (`yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss`)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe both your conjectures are correct.

And you have my sympathies for having to deal with that kind of monolithic code.